# R rgl package installation warning error

Tags: r

```
> library(rgl)

Warning messages:
1: In rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) : RGL: unable to open X11 display
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
```

I also  tried `plot3d` functions and I got the error:

```
Error in rgl.open(useNULL) : rgl.open failed
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You'll get more attention to this if you delete the Q from here and post it on StackOverflow with the `[r]` tag

Answer (score 3):

Your previous questions indicate that you're on Ubuntu: rgl depends on some gl packages to function.

What you may not know: you can install r-cran-rgl as a package

`$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl`

That will install all necessary dependencies and allow you to just load the package in R. It would probably be helpful to run `remove.packages("rgl")` from R first so that you have the correct version.